# как превратить блок div в раскрывающееся меню bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, меню

У меня есть боковое меню с фильтрами..

[image: Фильтры]

как можно сделать так чтобы на планшете и мобильной версии,чтобы этот блок превращался в раскрывающееся меню..типа такого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]